# How to run DBCC CHECKDB with both REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS and NOINDEX

Tags: checkdb

I have a very large database (233GB), and running DBCC CHECKDB with REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS is taking WAY too long (over 15 hours). There are a lot of indexes on a table that I would rather have removed, but cannot remove the table until the database is back up and running. Each index is taking AT LEAST 2 hours to check. Is there a way to run CHECKDB with both REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS AND NOINDEX?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MSSQL 10

Comment: You should add that information to the question and apply some relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

When you run DBCC CHEKDB with NOINDEX then, it skips indexes completely. NOINDEX does not affect system tables because integrity checks are always performed on system table indexes.

Check [this reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).